# Photos saved to iOS from Google Drive randomly downsized in resolution

Tags: google-apps, photos

Anybody experienced this please? How can I always have the original resolution?
Since these photos are exported from a raw to a gif on my laptop, they are around 4000x of resolution. 
Sometimes they are saved to my camera roll in the original resolution and sometimes they are downsized to about 1000x. 
In both cases I’m using the same saving process from Google Drive to iOS. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: For clarification, are you first saving your photos to Google Drive on your laptop, then opening the photos in the Google Drive app on your iPhone? Surely if you check the file size on Google Drive, the photo is in the big resolution?

Comment: Are you using Google Photos?

Comment: @ahorn hi sorry for my late reply. I’m uploading the original from my pc.

Comment: If you check the file size on Google Drive, surely the resolution is big?

Comment: @ahorn yes on google drive the size is ok. It’s when I downloaded to iOS that the resolution is lowered.

Comment: @MFJC I have 2 things. 1. how do you check the resolution on the iOS? visually? 2. Are the photos in RAW format? If both are yeses, please open the photo and click edit, it would take some time to load and then see if resolution is unaltered. You  might see a RAW appearing in the top corner. you can export it in JPEG via photos app to reduce the size and load time.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii i check the resolution with Snapseed, also a google app. No the pics are only in jpeg since I export them from a raw in ON1 Photo RAW on my pc.